# JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText) returns empty

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

I am using Ajax. My `search.php` contains the javascript code. It requests for `content.php` which echoes an array `$res` that contains values in the form of `"key" : value`.

**content.php :**

```
echo json_encode($res);
```

**search.php:**

```
 <!--Load the AJAX API-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"> </script>
 <script type="text/javascript">

var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {

alert(xmlhttp.responseText); //this alerts the correct content of $res but along with all the HTML page codes
var array = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText); //also tried json_decode(xmlhttp.responseText, true); and jQuery.parseJSON( xmlhttp.responseText );
alert(array); // this doesn't alert at all
}
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", "<?php echo   @$this->config->base_url();  ?>index.php/content.php", true);

xmlhttp.send();

</script>
```

However, when I print `$res` alone in a separate page, it shows the correct output which is:

```
{"1894":1,"1905":0,"1916":0,"1927":0,"1938":0,"1949":0,"1960":0,"1971":0,"1982":0,"1993":0,"2004":1,"2015":2}
```

I tried to loop through the array:

```
var array = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);

for(var index in array) {

 alert(index+ " is: "+ array[index]);
}
```

But this also doesn't alert anything.
I've been trying and searching on this for days but couldn't find a working solution.

**Edit:**

here is the output of `alert(xmlhttp.responseText)` :

[part 1 of the alert window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNt2s.png)

[part 2 of the alert window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c9iUC.png)

couldn't post more than two links (because I don't have enough reputation), anyway you had a glimpse of it, I believe.

Comment: what does `xmlhttp.responseText` look like?

Comment: "this alerts the correct content of $res *but along with the script codes*" seems important. Could you show the *exact*, full contents of `xmlhttp.responseText`?

Comment: Side note: the JSON shown does not represent array, so it may be better to not use confusing `array` name for variable - one may think that type of `array` is array.

Comment: Please make sure to post [MCVE] code that generates server response - it is unlikely that `echo json_encode($res);` alone adds extra "script codes".

Comment: I think you are missing a curly wurly brace to close the `onreadystatechange` function

Comment: Alexei Levenkov  it is not "script code", it's HTML. This was a mistake, sorry :)  i just edited the post.

Comment: RamRaider it is not missing in my actual code, just missed it when posting this. I just edited it anyway, but thanks for taking a shot.

Comment: Alexei Levenkov actually it is an array (or at least that's what i want it to be). if it really isn't an array, maybe that's what my whole problem is all about! can you please suggest how to do so? handle it as an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to what I can see in both images, your PHP is giving you HTML code after the JSON object, that could be the problem that stops you from parsing it. Make sure you end PHP execution after echoing `$res`. In other words, try with this line:

```
echo json_encode($res);exit;
```

Also, in case that doesn't work, please change `alert(xmlhttp.responseText)` to `console.log(xmlhttp.responseText)`, check the browser console and copy here all the text you get back from the server

Comment: this appears to be my problem thanks!! but the only issue with using `exit;` is that now it returns the content of `$res` alone (which is great), but then it stops executing everything else including the view code (so it shows the correct output but with a plain white page). Although the view code is in `search.php` (which is not the same file i used `exit;` in!)

Comment: @L.Ibra Well, that depends on a lot of things. The exit command stops all execution and returns. So if you use it before rendering the page, you'll get that problem. Since I don't really know how your entire code is, I'll take a guess and suggest you to do something like this: `xmlhttp.open("GET", "<?php echo   @$this->config->base_url();  ?>index.php/content.php?json=true", true);` and then, in the PHP, replace the line `echo json_encode($res);exit;` with `if(isset($_GET['json'])){echo json_encode($res);exit;}`

Comment: I really can't thank you enough. YOU SAVED ME!!! your suggestion worked perfectly!

Comment: @L.Ibra Hey, no problem, I'm glad I could help! :P

Answer (score -1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var url=<?php echo "'" . $this->config->base_url() . 'index.php/content.php';?>;
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {/* this was unclosed */
        if( xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200 ) {
            var r=xmlhttp.responseText;
            console.info('ajax response: %s ',r);
            var array = JSON.parse(r);
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open( "GET", url, true );
    xmlhttp.send();
</script>
```

Comment: this hasn't changed anything, but thanks for your time!